# Third highest salary using rank function in Postgres Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, top-n

Query for third highest salary using rank function

```
select * 
from (
    select emp_sal,row_number()over() as RANK 
    from (
       select emp_sal 
       from emp_demo 
       order by emp_sal desc
    )
)K 
where K.RANK=3
```

error coming as

```
*ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 1: ...m (select emp_sal,row_number()over() as RANK from (select em...
                                                             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
********** Error **********
ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
SQL state: 42601
Hint: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
Character: 63*
```

I am not able to display third highest salary in RazorSQL (also in Postgresql)

Comment: I think the error message is hinting what to correct, you are missing `AS` before your alias `K` in the code `from (select emp_sal from emp_demo order by emp_sal desc))K`. Can you try if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the contents of the `over` clause. Also, you should probably be using `dense_rank` and not `row_number` in case several employees have the same salary:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY emp_sal DESC) AS rk 
        FROM   emp_demo) t
WHERE  rk = 3
```

Comment: ..Thanks for the answer.. actually i tried using dense_rank but  result were not coming so i thought it would be better to start from basic that's why i used row_number().. still error was coming ...so i posted here the question.. thanks a Lot for logic....It working now..

Answer (score 2):

Below works

```
select *  from employee emp1 where (2) = (select count(distinct(emp2.salary))
         from employee emp2 where emp2.salary > emp1.salary )
```

the query works like a for a loop when the count is 0 means, it is the top highest maximum value.

when the count is 1, there is only one highest value greater than the current value. so it should be the second highest.

when the count is 2, there are two values greater than the current value. so it should be the third highest.

Alternative

```
select distinct(salary) as salary from employee order by salary desc offset 2 limit 1
```